# Title in ActionBar appears black

Tags: android, android-styles

I am having trouble finding out why the title in my action bar appears black, this only happens on an emulator with Android 4.1.1, which should be API 15.
Here is my default styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

and here is the styles from values-v15 and values-v14

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Styles -->
<style name="OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_about</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

what would be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style name="TitleTextColor">
    <item name="android:text">@string/app_name</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#a23421</item>
</style>
```

Edit:(new) Put this in the styles.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

For White text:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#f00</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: where do I put this and where to reference it, please explain more

Comment: Try to put in your resources.Btw, this for changing the textcolor on ActionBar.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am asking for, change the textcolor, but where  in STYLES.XML do I reference your answer?

Comment: You also have to tell us what´s not working. For example add the logcat to you question.

Comment: as I said its just that the title name appears black, only on Android 4.1.1, I want it to be white